# Git Bash global code editor

Tags: git

I have recently started to learn Git and I am going through the tutorial on git hub website. I am not finding the exact answer for this one therefore I am posting this question.

I am trying run commit command without comments and git bash launches code editor that says "Please enter the commit message...."

Is there a command to navigate back to git bash command prompt without entering the commit message on the code editor?

Thank you.

Comment: Close the code editor?

Comment: Can you post details of your OS and what editor is running?  On Unix/Linux systems `git` will use whatever is defined in your `$EDITOR` shell variable, often `vim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is running Vim then you can use `:cq` to exit with returning error, so Git will don't commit anything.

Comment: Or press Shift + z twice

Comment: Or just `:q`, because an empty message won’t commit by default either.

Comment: Yep, you booth are right, but my version can be called 'more secure' and 'more universal'.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't provide a commit message (and exit the editor), git will not perform the commit.

---

More generally, you might want to provide a commit message on the command line directly:

```
git commit [ your other options here ] -m 'this is the commit message'
```

or select your favourite editor by setting:

```
export GIT_EDITOR='emacs'
```

or
    export VISUAL='emacs'

(replace `emacs` with your favourite editor) before committing. You can do this in the bash startup files so you don't have to type it each time you open a new shell.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the command to simply quit the code editor.